# Bootstrap dropdown form width using col-*

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, width

I am trying to make dropdown login form in navigation bar using Bootstrap 3, but it does not look good - labels and inputs are wider than drop down ... panel.
How I can change drop down form width *using* **col-*** Bootstrap classes?

Here is the code (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal):

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Sign in <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could add padding to the `.dropdown-menu` and change your columns to `col-lg-11`

Example: http://bootply.com/110118